# Passing data in $.ajax request returns an empty array. What is wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am struggling with this.

I am trying to pass element data to my php file using $.ajax and it always returns empty.

Here is my code:

```
    strJson = '{'
    $.each(this_side.data(), function(i, v) {
        strJson += i + ":'" + v + "',";
    });
    strJson += term_id + ":'" + term_id + "',";
    strJson += new_page_num + ":'" + new_page_num + "'";
    strJson += '}';

    alert(strJson); // this works

    $.ajax({
        url: 'my url here',
        type: 'post',
        data: strJson,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Outpot of $_POST is an empty array. It's not working.

What I am missing here please???

Comment: also (not the problem), it should be `done`, not `success`. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: post the error in console log

Comment: you should escape the `i` too: `strJson += "'"+ i + "':'" + v + "',";`

Comment: and data has to be a JSON object, not a JSON string: `data : JSON.parse(strJson),`

Answer (score 1):

don't bother with `dataType` and `contentType`, jQuery should to that on its own.
what does `this_side.data()` return? if it is an array, then your `i` variable in your `$.each` loop is a number, and your JSON is simply wrongly formatted. try

```
$.each(this_side.data(), function(i, v) {
    strJson += "'" + i + "':'" + v + "',";
});
```

and then you should also post a JSON object, not a JSON string:

```
 $.ajax({
    data : JSON.parse( strJson ),
    ...
 })
```

this takes also into account when `this_side.data()` returns an object and the keys have 'special' characters like '-'.

if `this_side.data()` returns an object, the following is way easier:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my url here',
    type: 'post',
    data: $.extend( 
            this_side.data(),
            {'term_id': term_id, 'new_page_num' : new_page_num }
          ),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer due to lordVlad comment:

```
strJson = '{'
    $.each(this_side.data(), function(i, v) {
        strJson += i + ":'" + v + "',";
    });
    strJson += "'"+ i + "':'" + v + "',";
    strJson += new_page_num + ":'" + new_page_num + "'";
    strJson += '}';
```

Try to add `dataType` and 'contentType' to your code

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'my url here',
        type: 'post',
        data : JSON.parse(strJson),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
```

Also you may want to check official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my url here',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { param: strJson },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `dataType:"json"` too:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my url here',
    type: 'post',
    data: $.parseJSON(strJson),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and parse the `strJson` with `$.parseJSON()` before sending.

Answer (score 0):

In data parameter you are sending a string in json format.

Try sending data in following format.

```
strJson='name=Will&address=florida';
```

Let me know if this works.